# BibLaTeX - Conditionnal citation style based on langid or institution (legal case citations)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle, legal-style, oscola

I'm new to BibLaTeX tinkering. I'm trying to build a modified citation style based on `verbose-trad2` that would suit my needs, which are :

1. **Change citation style according to the `langid` field** - I want to cite french and english legal cases. The problem is both have very different styles of citation, but are categorized under the same @entryType in BibLaTeX (@jurisdiction). I'm using Zotero to build the .bib, so building a custom @entryType is out of the way. My initial idea was to use the `\iffieldequalstrg` command of the biblatex package, but it is somewhat limited.
2. **Change citation style according to `institution` field** - In France, citation styles for legal cases depends on the institution you're citing. For example :

- C.E., 6 février 1981, Ministre de l’intérieur c. Benhamou, Rec. T., 795. (for the Conseil d'Etat) ;
- C. const., n° 2004-503 DC, 12 août 2004, Loi relative aux libertés et responsabilités locales, Rec. 144 (for the Conseil constitutionnel).

As you can see, the number is not at the same place in both citations. I also tried to use a condition command, but as the field `institution` is a litteral list, it can not accept a string as a value to test. Anyway, I'm stuck and can't find a solution.

Here is the code I came up with so far. It is quite messy and probably insufficiently optimized. There are other changes I made to the style, the part we're interested in here is at the end.

This code is located in a file called `cit-style.tex` which I include in the main document :

```
\usepackage[%
citestyle=verbose-trad2,%\texttt{}
bibstyle=verbose,%
citepages=omit,%
sorting=nyt,%
backref=true,%
isbn=false,%
url=false,%
doi=false,%
eprint=false,%
related=false,%
giveninits=true,%
autopunct=false % Permet de ne pas changer le marqueur de place - le problème étant que les erreurs de double ponctuation sont toujours possibles. Trouver une solution.
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{guillemets}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareListFormat{parentheses-liste}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Changement de la chaîne de caractère Références to Bibliographie
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{references={Bibliographie}}

% Changement du séparateur en virgule au lieu du point moche. 
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{\addcomma\addspace}

% Virgule à la place du deux points entre le lieu et l'éditeur.
\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+series+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printtext{coll.\space}%
    \printfield[guillemets]{series}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
    \printtext{coll.\addspace}
    \printfield[guillemets]{series}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \newunit}

% Redéfinition de la macro affichant le titre de la revue et la date de publication (pour enlever les parenthèses).
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \iffieldundef{number}%
    {}%
    {\addcomma\addspace%
        \printtext{\bibstring{number}}\addspace\printfield{number}}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{volume}%
    {}%
    {\printtext{\bibstring{volume}}\addspace\printfield{volume}}
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

% Redéfinition de la macro qui affiche la date des articles.
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printtext{%
        \addcomma\addspace%
        \printfield{issue}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}  

% Format NOM Prénom 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} %retire virgule entre les noms
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\mkbibparens{#1}} % ajoute des parenthèses autour des initiales du prénom.


\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{{\emph{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{ }

% Redéfinition du driver Book pour afficher la collection après l'éditeur et la ville.

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+series+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{pagetotal}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
        \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro{uk-case-cit}{% Macro which prints the citation for English case (without the title of the case) - Condition is important in order to print the brackets or not.
    \iffieldundef{volume}{% If the entry has no volume field, then the year of the report is important - brackets.
        \printfield[brackets]{year}%
    }%
    {% No brackets if no volume
        \printfield[parens]{year}
    }%
    \addspace%
    \printfield[default]{journaltitle}% prints the report title
    \addspace%
    \printfield[default]{pages}% prints the page
}%

\newbibmacro{fr-juridiction+date}{% for all french cases, prints the institution name and the date. I want this part to be conditionnal.
    \printlist{institution}%
    \newunit%
    \printdate%
}%

\newbibmacro{neutral-cit-oscola}{% prints the neutral citation if one has been filed in the .bib.
    \printfield{number}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{uk-case-cit}%
}%

\newbibmacro{oscola-juris}{% Prints the full english case citation. Based on the OSCOLA guidelines.
    \printfield{title}%
    \addspace%
    \iffieldundef{number}{%
        \usebibmacro{uk-case-cit}
    }%
    {%
        \usebibmacro{neutral-cit-oscola}%
    }%
    \addspace%
    \printlist[parentheses-liste]{institution}%
}%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{jurisdiction}{ % Definition of the driver for the @jurisdiction entries.
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \iffieldequalstr{langid}{french}{% Is the entry a french case ? 
        \usebibmacro{fr-juridiction+date}
        \newunit%
        \usebibmacro{title}% This is where I would also like to insert a condition to print different citation styles according to the institution field.
    }%
    {% If not french, then prints following oscola guidelines.
        \usebibmacro{oscola-juris}%
    }%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

MWE 1 - `main.tex` :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{varioref}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\input{cit-style.tex}

\begin{document}

\textbf{English Case (brackets because year of the report is important) :}

\cite{rice1911}

\textbf{English Case (parenthesis because year is not that important for the report)}

\cite{cooperWilson1937}

\textbf{Case from the French Conseil d'Etat :}

\cite{untitled2007}


\end{document}
```

MWE 2 - `biblio.bib` :

```
@jurisdiction{rice1911,
    title = {Board of {{Education}} v {{Rice}}},
    date = {1911},
    journaltitle = {A.C.},
    pages = {179},
    institution = {{UKHL}},
    url = {http://www.commonlii.org/uk/cases/UKLawRpAC/1911/18.html},
    langid = {english}
}

@jurisdiction{cooperWilson1937,
    title = {Cooper v {{Wilson}}},
    date = {1937-03-27},
    journaltitle = {K.B.},
    volume = {2},
    number = {[1937] 2 K.B. 309},
    pages = {9},
    institution = {{Court of Appeal}},
    urldate = {2023-10-11},
    langid = {english}
}

@jurisdiction{untitled2007,
    title = {Untitled},
    date = {2007-02-22},
    journaltitle = {Publié au recueil Lebon},
    number = {264541},
    institution = {{Conseil d'État}},
    url = {https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/ceta/id/CETATEXT000018259406/},
    urldate = {2023-03-14},
    langid = {french},
    annotation = {Section du Contentieux}
}
```

I compile everything with **XeLaTeX in TexStudio**, on MacOs 14 Sonoma (MBA M2).

To sum up, I'm trying to find a way to make style conditioning easier. I can't find enough documentation on this in the biblatex manual. Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Thanks a lot, have a nice week-end!

Hurj